# Operator '&&' cannot be applied operands to bool and bool?

Tags: c#, linq

Sample query

```
var users = (from t in T_Table
            join x in X_Table on t.id equals x.id
            where t.pid == x.pid
            && somelist.contains(t.id) //UNABLE TO APPLY somelist?.contains
            select (new User(){name = t.user})).ToList();
```

I'm unable null check somelist.

It shows:

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied operands to bool and bool?

Comment: The above code does not compile.

Comment: @mjwills I posted sample code, main concern is not able to null check somelist

Comment: What is `somelist`?

Comment: This is where a [mcve] would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

problem here is if you write like this

`somelist?.contains(t.id)` return null in case  somelist is `null` and null is not boolean value.

So you should try like this

```
  &&  (somelist!=null ? somelist.contains(t.id) : false)
```

Check : [3 misuses of ?. operator in C# 6](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/05/11/3-misused-of-operator-in-c-6/)

Answer (score 4):

Your error occurs becasue

```
bool b1 = true;
bool? b2 = true;
bool result = b1 && b2; //b2 could also be null
```

There are two ways to solve this.

## 1

```
bool result = b1 && b2 == true;  // somelist?.contains() == true
```

## 2

make sure your item can't be null before you run your query (this also works for linq2SQL) so you don't need a null-conditional operator in your query

```
if(somelist == null)
{
   somelist = new List<yourType>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check if somelist is not null first before accessing contains.

```
var users = (from t in T_Table
            join x in X_Table on t.id equals x.id
            where t.pid == x.pid
            && somelist != null && somelist.contains(t.id) //UNABLE TO APPLY somelist?.contains
            select (new User(){name = t.user})).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

First check whether somelist is having any data or not, if somelist is null you can't operate contains on somelist

or

```
Where(u => somelist.Contains(t.Id.Value))
```

should also work if somelist is not null